# How to make background image and the content over the image responsive especially if the content is large

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have an image in the background and some buttons over the image. My image becomes responsive by including some styling, but the content which is above the image is causing the image to repeat itself.

**HTML:**

```
<header class="mainheader" style="background-image:url(home.jpg);height:864px;">
  <!--  -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" style="background-color:white">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a> -->
  </div>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#" style="color:#FFFFFF">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color:#FFFFFF">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color:#EC5297;">Login</a></li>
      <li>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn seeit">See it in Action</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn signp">Signup for FREE</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--line-->
  <hr class="line">
  <div class="container">
    <!--responsive karna hain-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 twobutton">
        <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn one" style="width:130px;">Signup for FREE</button>
        <p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn two" style="width:130px;">See it in Action</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--for-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 for">
        <p>For</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--buttons-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="margin-left: 35em;">
        <img src="quvunew - Light [Recovered].png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--content-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 content">
        <p style="color:#FFFFFF;">Send notifications to your users, even when they're not on your website Implement Chrome & Firefox Push Notifications on any Website in 5 mins
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--content-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 imagetwo">
        <img src="content.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--signup-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 signup">
        <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn   one" style="width:226px;">Signup for FREE</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--header image close-->
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mainheader {
  no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

#rightnav {}

.seeit {
  background-color: Transparent;
  color: white;
  width: 166 px;
  height: 35 px;
}

.signp {
  background-color: #766DCC;
  color: white;
}

.line {
  color: #457AA9;
}

.twobutton {
  margin-top: 300px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.one {
  background-color: #766DCC;
}

.two {
  background-color: Transparent;
  color: white;
}

.for {
  margin-top: 5em;
  margin-left: 41em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.centerimg {
  /*margin-left: 12em;*/
}

.content {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.imagetwo {
  margin-top: 3em;
}

.signup {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.backgroundimage {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 1400px;
  width: 1280px;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
.mainheader {
  no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

there is something missing in the first line: the parameter for these settings. Remove the background-image attribute from the `header` tag in the HTML and put it into the CSS:

```
.mainheader {
  background: url(home.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

and your header tag should then be:

```
<header class="mainheader" style="height:864px;">
```

Or better also move that height setting from the style attribute to the CSS rule...

ADDITION: Actually `background-size: 100% auto;` should be `background-size: cover;`, if you want it to behave like the prefixed settings you listed right before that. (I changed that above)